# How to use python to open existing .xlsx paste dataframe to a specified spreadsheet and location without wiping other tabs and values?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to copy a dataframe from a .csv file and paste it into an existing .xls file in a specified sheet and a specified location.

This code writes the dataframe to the existing excel file, but it overwrites the file completely. The workbook consists of other tabs too.
the outcome was, it copied and pasted to the specified location,
but other tabs and cell values got wiped out too.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import csv
import xlsxwriter

from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart import LineChart,Reference 

from win32com.client import Dispatch
import os

from pandas import ExcelWriter

xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

#record start time
currentDT_start =datetime.datetime.now()

# Read index data from .csv
index_file=r"file\name\.."
analysis_file=r"file\name.."

py_index_file=index_file.replace('\\','\\\\')
py_analysis_file=analysis_file.replace('\\','\\\\')

#copying 
index = pd.read_csv(py_index_file,skiprows=1)
#print(index.head())



#this code write the dataframe to the existing excel file, but it overwrite the file completely. the workbook consists of other tabs too.
# the outcome was it copied and pasted to specified location
# but other tabs and cells values got wiped out too.

writer=ExcelWriter(py_analysis_file)
index.to_excel(writer,'Indexes',startrow=1)
writer.save()


currentDT_end=datetime.datetime.now()

print('Code started on ' + currentDT_start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + ' !')
print('Code completed on ' + currentDT_end.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + ' !')
```

Comment: Use openpyxl directly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the format you are using for `to_excel` isn't correct according to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#writing-excel-files-to-disk).  You need to pass a `sheet_name` in as the second argument.

Try doing below instead:

```py
with ExcelWriter(py_analysis_file) as writer:
    index.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Indexes')
```